# Gnuplot and VSCode's Latex Workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a contour plot with PGFPlots in VSCode. I am using the LaTeX Workshop extension. I have gnuplot installed. Also in case it matters, I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux 1 (WSL1).  I have enabled shell escape too (and I know it is working because I've compiled files with the `minted` package just fine). Lastly, I am compiling with LuaLaTeX.

I have a main tex file and in that I have something like this

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xlabel = {X},
                ylabel = {Y}
            ]
            \addplot3 [
                contour gnuplot
            ] table {Code/Data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

When I try to compile I get an error that `main_contourtmp0.table` could not be opened. That's because it is not being created. I can see that `main_contourtmp0.dat` and `main_contourtmp0.script` are both there in my file directory.

It seems that Latex Workshop cannot find gnuplot.

Any suggestions or thoughts on how I can correct it?

There is an `env` variable in the `recipes` section of LaTeX Workshop. Maybe I could append a path to `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot` or something like that?

Comment: I tried compiling with `pdflatex` and I get the error. Even though I have shell escape enabled, it can't find gnuplot, despite gnuplot being in the `PATH`. Really stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627955/cant-load-shared-library-libqt5core-so-5). I had to run the following command since I am using WSL1.

`sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5`

After running this command it compiles just fine.